# Picker scroll through one element horizontally

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uipickerview

I have a SwiftUI Picker in which an item is selected. The text of one element can be large, so I used UIKit UIPickerView and set the manual height to 100, but at some point it became not enough. Is it possible to make scrolling horizontal for each element?

I want to get something like this:

```
Picker("Items", select: self._selectItem) {
    ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            Text(item.description)
        }
        .tag(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine. If you only want to scroll one item, you would have to insert a check of the item length.

```
let items = [
    "A long item text.",
    "And a even longer item text which is really going further.",
    "Another item text which is really going further."
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var select = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Make your selection!")
            
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    Text(item)
                }
                .listRowBackground(item == select ? Color.red : Color.white)
                .onTapGesture {
                    select = item
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to separate the picking from the text display and scrolling, e.g. like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var select = items[0]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Make your selection!")
            
            Picker("Items", selection: $select) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                        .tag(item)
                }
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                Text(select.text)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example, but my problem is that item.title has a lot of characters and does not fit in the display window. And due to the fact that the initial characters of items may be similar, it is not clear how they differ.

Comment: ah ok, would it make sense to swipe through the different items ? so you can have each one full screen?

Comment: I'm thinking of using a `List` and making a choice through it

Comment: I want to be able to scroll through all the list of items vertically and scroll one item from this list horizontally.